# angular2 validate form on button click

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

If I submit a form using `button type="submit"` the form validation messages appear and everything is fine.  However if I have a button (or link) with `(click)="myhandler()"` then the validations do not appear.

How can I either:

- tag the element as requiring validators to run, or
- programatically run and show validation messages.

Note: These are simple validations like required on input fields.

Sample Code:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="save()">                       
  <input required type='text' [(ngModel)]="name">
  <!-- Shows validation messages but still calls save() -->
  <button (click)="save()">Click</button>  
  <!-- Only submits if valid and shows messages -->       
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>         
</form>
<!-- does not even show validation messages, just calls save -->
<button (click)="save()">Click 2</button>
```

Comment: please provide code. I think problem is with your code.

Comment: its button type 'submit' or its an simple button, does related with validation, provide your code work we will help you

Comment: ans is short hope helps, add a hidden div based on form.validate  i.e `<div [hidden]="!form.validate">{{warningMessage}}</div>`

Answer (score 24):

Please note: this approach is for reactive forms.

I used `markAsTouched()` property to run validations on a button click.

Suppose the following button is outside the form:

```
<button type="button" (click)="validateForm()">Submit</button>
```

Now, in the `validateForm` method if the form is invalid, you can set `markAsTouched()` property for each of the form controls and angular will show validation messages.

```
validateForm() {
    if (this.myformGroup.invalid) {
      this.myformGroup.get('firstName').markAsTouched();
      this.myformGroup.get('surname').markAsTouched();
      return;
    }
    // do something else
}
```

provided you have validation messages setup in your html like

```
<mat-error *ngIf="myformGroup.get('firstName').hasError('required')">
  first name is required
</mat-error>
```

and you have required field validation setup in your form group builder like

```
firstName: ['', Validators.required]
```

Answer (score 3):

Below Code Will Help You .. Tested with Angular 4 Latest version 4.2.4

```
<form method="post" #f="ngForm" name="form" novalidate="novalidate" class="form">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-12" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!listname.valid && (listname.dirty || listname.touched || f.submitted)}">
         <label for="listname">Name</label>
         <input id="listname" name="listname" type="text" [(ngModel)]="listData.title"
         required="true" placeholder="List Name" #listname="ngModel" class="form-control"/>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group text-right col-md-12 visible-md visible-lg">
         <button type="button"  name="save"  (click)="f._submitted = true;saveAndPublish=false;saveList(f.valid)" class="btn btn-default">Save
         Save List
         </button>
         <button type="button"  name="saveandpublish" (click)="f._submitted = true;saveAndPublish=true;saveList(f.valid);" class="btn btn-primary">Save
         & Publish  List
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

in Your .ts File

```
saveList(isValid: boolean) {
    if (isValid) {
      console.log(this.listData)
    }

  }
```

Comment: should be (click)="f.submitted...' instead of (click)="f._submitted...' Best answer.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Button with type submit triggers form submit automatically, i guess you have to trigger form submit manually:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="save()" #form="ngForm">

<button (click)="form.onSubmit()">Click 2</button>
```

> Why "ngForm"? A directive's exportAs property tells Angular how to link local variable to the directive. We set name to ngForm because the NgControlName directive's exportAs property happens to be "ngForm".

[documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html)

Comment: I tried `<form... #myform>` and on the button `<button (click)="myform.submit()"` and this did not run the validators.

Comment: nope, that gives error: 'onSubmit is not a function'

Comment: lets add `#form="ngForm"`.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep the button disabled until the form is valid. So in your case change your form element opening tag to create a variable for the form:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="save()" #myForm="ngForm">
```

and disable the button when the form isn't valid

`<button (click)="save()" [disabled]="!myForm.form.valid">Click 2</button>`

Let me know if that works. As the form itself will validate automatically and constantly in anycase, you dont need to call for it to be done.

Comment: This looks promising but I dont want to disable the button, I want it to trigger the nice pop up messages.  Does NgForm have a runValidatorsAndSubmit or something? Would like to do: `<button (click)="myForm.runValidatorsAndSubmit()"` if its available.  I dumped the ngForm to the console but found nothing like that.

Answer (score 1):

put conditions in [hidden] directive and change submitted property to true on submit!

```
<div [hidden]="email.valid || (email.untouched && !submitted) || !submitted" class="alert callout">
    <span [hidden]="!email.hasError('required')">Required</span>
</div>

onSubmit(){
   this.submitted = true
}
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: `onSubmit()` will not be called if the form is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `click2` button within `form` tag. It will start working !

```
<form (ngSubmit)="save()">                       
  <input required type='text' [(ngModel)]="name">
  <!-- Shows validation messages but still calls save() -->
  <button (click)="save()">Click</button>  
  <!-- Only submits if valid and shows messages -->       
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>     
  <!-- this will work now -->
  <button (click)="save()">Click 2</button>      
</form>
```

Comment: I have it outside on purpose, moving it inside however still calls save (as shown in the first button)

Comment: FYI...In your example you are not using angular2 for validation. The way you do it , it uses HTML5 for the validation. To validate for with Angular2, you have to deal with `ngFormModel,formBuilder,ngControl` directives. this might help you - http://plnkr.co/edit/oP0A8vWFHsZ4y5A7uUQP?p=preview.

Comment: Well that could be where I'm going wrong, perhaps the 'nice pop up' messages are HTML5!! Thanks, at least an avenue for investigateion

Comment: Thanks, I looked at your example a find out that I  accidentally has added <a> instead of <button> to submit form, and validations were not executed

Answer (score 0):

> Programatically check and disable using validation

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id='myForm' role="form" [ngFormModel]="CreateGroup">
  <div class="col-md-7">
    Name: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='demoInfo.name' class="form-control" ngControl='name'>
  </div>
  Form Valid : {{CreateGroup.valid}} 
</form>
<br>
<div class='text-center'>
  <button type="button" [disabled]='!CreateGroup.valid' (click)="addNewGroup(demoInfo)" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
</div>
```

working example http://plnkr.co/edit/aoHHw709VeMlP8Qfgnp6?p=preview

Comment: the problem with disabling the button is that the nice pop up messages do not show.

Comment: Yes if a required field is empty and you submit the form a nice 'Please fill in this field' pop up appears.  I like that.