# Angular2 Form : trigger or update validation properly & programmatically

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, redux, angular2-forms

I'm building a Wizard in Angular2 - Redux. I'm using Reactive Forms to handle & submit data for every step inside. I need to trigger form validation programmatically, because the declaration of my call-to-action button, in order to go to the next step, is in a separated component from the stepComponent. *See wireframe below*

**Components's wireframe**

[image]

**Current Behavior**

1. Only when a change has ocurred on a form's control, its own validation
   runs. And it's `touched & valid` property is updated accordingly.
2. As I am in a Redux environment, I dispatch an action to get the
   current-step form data in order to be applied to the payload. When
   that's is finished, I trigger another action to save data.
3. Actually, I know when the form is valid or invalid by using:

   ```
    submitForm(form: FormGroup):void{
       if(form.valid){
         this.actionsStep.saveStep(form.value);
       }else{
         console.log('Form invalid ')
       }
     }
   ```
4. As my forms uses controls's properties to render a custom message
   when a error has happened, I want to re-run validation
   by submit the form or by using another function to be able to use
   the control's properties again to notify where an error has occurred.

**StepComponent.ts : Form declaration**

```
this.stepForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

**step-component.html : Form HTML**

```
<form id="ngForm" [formGroup]="stepForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(stepForm.value)" class="form-horizontal form-box-content">
    <div class="form-group row" [ngClass]="{'has-danger' :name.invalid && name.touched}">
      <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Name:</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <input 
        name="titulo" class="form-control required" 
               formControlName="name" placeholder="" type="text"  [ngClass]="{'form-control-danger' :name.invalid && name.touched}" >
        <small class="form-control-feedback text-danger" *ngIf="name.invalid && name.touched && name.hasError('required')">
          The name is required
        </small>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**Attemps**

I tried to use

1. Update Validity:

   `this.stepForm.updateValueAndValidity();`
2. Update Validity providing params:

   `this.stepForm.updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: false, emitEvent: true });`
3. Mark each control as touched (To trigger event as I've typed something)

   `for (var i in this.stepForm.controls) {
     this.stepForm.controls[i].markAsTouched();
   }`
4. The solutions which requires submit function to be called from the HTML
   will not work for me because the button and the form are in separated components.

**5. Is there any way to trigger or update validation programmatically or at least to submit a form properly in a function?**

**Previous Research**

I found many help links to achieve this, however,those solutions work only when the button is declared in the same component. And also, when button is inside the `form` tag:

- [Angular2 - Validate and submit form from outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38054631/angular2-validate-and-submit-form-from-outside) : Work only in
  the same component
- [angular2 validate form on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36569847/angular2-validate-form-on-button-click) : Work only in the same component
- [Angular 2 Submit button outside of form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39413159/angular-2-submit-button-outside-of-form) : Not working
- [Is there a way to
  submit an Angular 2 model-driven form (reactive form) from a outside
  button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880470/is-there-a-way-to-submit-an-angular-2-model-driven-form-reactive-form-from-a-o) : Refers to previous link

Comment: What is the problem you are facing with the current approach?

Comment: Can you construct a minimal working example?

Comment: @HarryNinh , the problem is that I can not trigger the form validation from js . I wonder if there is any way to do this. 
I was thinking that by  submitting the form would result that inner validation runs; however, I do not find a way to submit from js, either.

Comment: Ok so short version: 1) the form is automatically validated every time a field value is updated; 2) you can retrieve form value and do HTTP POST request to submit the form

Comment: @HarryNinh thanks about that. So, actually there's no way to validate the form manually, without the need to updated or touch the controls, is it?

Comment: @leonardovidal I don't fully get your intention here, why do you need to re-validate an untouched form? Say you have 2 variables `a = 1` and `b = 1`, no matter how many time you do `a + b`, the result is still is `2`. A form that has the same value will always be either valid or invalid no matter how many times you validate it.

Comment: I can understand your point. My goal is to show what fields are not filled correctly or empty when the user click the next button. This is a common user's behavior for any form on submit. Currently,  in html, the error messages are connected with the property valid & touched. And only when they are touched and then lost the focus with incorrect information, like empty , the control updates its properties in  the component and the view properly. Is there a way to mark all controls as touched and run validation for each of them  in a function?

Answer (score 0):

I basically had the same setup, and got around it by doing the equivalent of

```
(this.stepForm as any).submitted = true
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is still trying to do this. I did this by using ViewChild to grab references to the referenced components and stepper. Then control the next button click and do not have matStepperNext on the button.

```
<button mat-button (click)="onStepOneNextClick()">Next</button>

@ViewChild(MatStepper) stepper: MatStepper;
@ViewChild(StepOneComponent, { static: true }) stepOneComponent: StepOneComponent;

onStepOneNextClick() {
  if (this.stepOneComponent.form.invalid) {
    this.stepOneComponent.form.markAllAsTouched();
  }
  else {
    this.stepper.next();
  }
}
```